# How to restructure extra wide-format data into a long format?

Tags: r, tidyr

I have a dataset that has information for 22 instructors, each associated with 4 groups of students. Each group of the student's data spans across 64 columns. In R, I would like to restructure this dataset into a long format, where each student is represented in a separate row. Below is a simplified version of my data, featuring only two instructors, their schools, and gender and age for the students. Please note that the actual dataset contains a more comprehensive set of information, encompassing both demographic and non-demographic details.

| Instructor | Instructor school | Student1 age | Student1 gender | Student2 age | Student2 gender | Student3 age | Student3 gender | Student4 age | Student4 gender |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| John | X | 18 | male | 18 | female | 16 | female | 17 | male |
| Jane | Y | 16 | female | 15 | male | 16 | male | 18 | female |

The desired structure is as follows:

| Instructor | Instructor school | Student | Information |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| John | X | 1 | 18 |
| John | X | 1 | male |
| John | X | 2 | 18 |
| John | X | 2 | female |
| John | X | 3 | 16 |
| John | X | 3 | female |
| John | X | 4 | 17 |
| John | X | 4 | male |
| Jane | Y | 1 | 16 |
| Jane | Y | 1 | female |
| Jane | Y | 2 | 15 |
| Jane | Y | 2 | male |
| Jane | Y | 3 | 16 |
| Jane | Y | 3 | male |
| Jane | Y | 4 | 18 |
| Jane | Y | 4 | female |

For my sample, I used the following:

```
original_data <- data.frame(
  Instructor = c("John", "Jane"),
  Instructor_school = c("X", "Y"),
  Student1_age = c(18, 16),
  Student1_gender = c("male", "female"),
  Student2_age = c(18, 15),
  Student2_gender = c("female", "male"),
  Student3_age = c(16, 16),
  Student3_gender = c("female", "male"),
  Student4_age = c(17, 18),
  Student4_gender = c("male", "female")
)


# Reshape the data to long format
long_data <- original_data %>%
  gather(key = "key", value = "value", -Instructor, -Instructor_school) %>%
  separate(col = key, into = c("Student", "Info"), sep = "_") %>%
  mutate(Student = gsub("Student", "", Student))

View(long_data)
```

And I got the intended output with some difference in sorting.

| Instructor | Instructor school | Student | Info | Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| John | X | 1 | age | 18 |
| Jane | Y | 1 | age | 16 |
| John | X | 1 | gender | male |
| Jane | Y | 1 | gender | female |
| John | X | 2 | age | 18 |
| Jane | Y | 2 | age | 15 |
| John | X | 2 | gender | female |
| Jane | Y | 2 | gender | male |
| John | X | 3 | age | 16 |
| Jane | Y | 3 | age | 16 |
| John | X | 3 | gender | female |
| Jane | Y | 3 | gender | male |
| John | X | 4 | age | 17 |
| Jane | Y | 4 | age | 18 |
| John | X | 4 | gender | male |
| Jane | Y | 4 | gender | female |

But I can't figure out how to apply this restructuring when each instructor has 9 columns (FirstName, LastName, School, Email, etc.) and each student group (Student1, Student2, Student3, and Student4) has 64 columns (the column names are inconsistent). The only pattern I have is for the students: the columns are organized in such a way that values between "Student1 age" and "Student2 age" (the 63 columns in between) belong to student 1. And the same goes for the rest.

I would really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this would work?

```
original_data |>
  pivot_longer(3:10, 
               names_to = c("Student", "stat"), names_sep = "_", 
               values_to = "Information", values_transform = as.character)
```

Result

```
# A tibble: 16 × 5
   Instructor Instructor_school Student  stat   Information
   <chr>      <chr>             <chr>    <chr>  <chr>      
 1 John       X                 Student1 age    18         
 2 John       X                 Student1 gender male       
 3 John       X                 Student2 age    18         
 4 John       X                 Student2 gender female     
 5 John       X                 Student3 age    16         
 6 John       X                 Student3 gender female     
 7 John       X                 Student4 age    17         
 8 John       X                 Student4 gender male       
 9 Jane       Y                 Student1 age    16         
10 Jane       Y                 Student1 gender female     
11 Jane       Y                 Student2 age    15         
12 Jane       Y                 Student2 gender male       
13 Jane       Y                 Student3 age    16         
14 Jane       Y                 Student3 gender male       
15 Jane       Y                 Student4 age    18         
16 Jane       Y                 Student4 gender female
```